# how to fit menu categories for full row in divi (wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, divi

I created a menu and don't understand how to fit/strech it for full row.

[want do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFVoY.png)

works only margin options, but it's not an optimal option.

for unclear reasons all other methods I tryed to use didn't work. (display-flex or text-align: justify). And this actual only for menu block, but works for other sections.

Comment: `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` on the container that holds all the items

Comment: .et_pb_menu_0 .et-menu-nav li a {
      
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        
    }

do that, but still doesn't work

Comment: an `<a>`-element doesn't seem like a container for all the items to me

Comment: but why menu have reaction on margin-left: 30px; but doesn't react on margin: auto; ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.